# SpringBoot REST API MockMVC testing not creating users successfully, despite the same functionality working in React project

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

I have a method within my UserController of my SpringBoot REST API that signs up a user, by parsing a json object into a string and then creating a new User object and storing it in the database using the JPA repository.

In my separate CORS React frontend project when the user goes to the home page, a POST request is sent to the API that signs a user up successfully (as a test) with a JSON payload of:

```
{username: "mitton", password: "JohnSmith72-"}
```

This works fine and when I go to the React project /home I can see that the user was created and saved successfully, so I know this  functionality does work.

I am trying to test this controller method using JUnit and MockMVC but when I try to make the same POST request using mockMVC a 200 is returned, but no User is created.

UserControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Test
public void addUserTest() throws Exception {

    TestUser testUser = new TestUser("timcard", "TimCard72-");

    mvc.perform(post("http://localhost:8080/users/signup")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(asJsonString(testUser)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    Optional<User> user = userService.getUser(1L);
    Optional<User> justInCaseUser = userService.getUser(1L);
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    System.out.println(justInCaseUser.toString());

}

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(jsonContent);
            return jsonContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

MockMVC request / response / what is printed:

```
{"username":"timcard","password":"TimCard72-"}
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

Full successful react request:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const payload2 = {
            "username": "mitton",
            "password": "JohnSmith72-"
        }
        fetch(SIGNUP_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload2)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
}
```

In request browser:
General:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/users/signup
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Headers:

```
 Accept: application/json
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 47
    Content-Type: application/json
    Host: localhost:8080
    Origin: http://localhost:3000
    Referer: http://localhost:3000/
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Microsoft Edge";v="96"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.41
```

Payload:

```
{username: "mitton", password: "JohnSmith72-"}
```

The reason I created a TestUser class to use as a temporary object class to map the JSON payload in the test as opposed to using the User entity class is because when I create the User entity object, it automatically generates the ID field, and this would cause issues as the controller logic is supposed to only work with a json string as above with a username, password, not also a generated ID.

TestUser:

```
    @Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestUser {
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080"})
public class UserController {

        final
        UserService userService;


        public UserController(UserService userService) {
                this.userService = userService;
}

        @PostMapping("/signup")
        public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
                userService.signUpUser(user);
        }
}
```

UserService:

```
public void signUpUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

I feel as if the TestUser thing might be breaking it, but it wasn't working when I was just using the User entity either, because the value for id was being generated automatically:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")

    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }
}
```

Comment: And why should it? You are mocking the service... SO whatever the service does it doesn't as the instance is replaced with a mocked instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh so is there any way to do this without creating a mocked service, or anything? I really just wanted to test it as if the React project was sending requests to the API. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `@MockBean` just use `@Autowired` ... It isn't anymore complex than that. Or use the mocked instance and just verify if the services save method is called instead of trying to see if the user is saved in the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your help, works fine!

Comment: @M.Deinum By the way, if I had another test to login, is there a way to use the signed up user from this test? Or would I have to duplicate the above code in the Login test, prior to adding the login stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Well you could use them but having tests depend on each other is generally speaking a bad idea. If your test order changes, or add new tests things change and you suddenly endup with hard to trackdown test failures.